# Is information security less hard in an open source system?

Tags: kernel, security, source-code

In the excellent article [Why Information Security is Hard - An Economic Perspective](https://www.acsac.org/2001/papers/110.pdf), Ross Anderson poses that:

> ... you can make the security critical part of the system small enough that the bugs can be found. This was understood, in an empirical way, by the early 1970s. However, the discussion in the above section should have made clear that a minimal [TCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing_base) is unlikely to be available anytime soon, as it would make applications harder to develop and thus impair the platform vendors’ appeal to developers.

The "above section" mentions:

> The huge first-mover advantages that can arise in economic systems with strong positive feedback are the origin of the so-called "Microsoft philosophy" of
>   'we'll ship it on Tuesday and get it right by version 3'. Although sometimes attributed by cynics to a personal moral failing on the part of Bill Gates, this is perfectly rational behaviour in many markets where network economics apply.

I would like to understand if this also applies to an open-source kernels such as Linux, BSD, Hurd. Intuitively I would think that it only applies to a lesser extent, but that this pressure is not altogether non-existent. My main question is therefore:

> Is the [TBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing_base) in an open-source system **quantifiably** smaller?

If so, is this the consequence of:

1. UNIX modular design
2. continuous scrutiny of open-source code
3. lesser pressure to get to market fast
4. lesser pressure to court [developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE)
5. other ...

Apologies if I got the terminology or something else wrong. Feel free to edit, or comment so that I can edit.

Comment: While it's an interesting question, it is unfit for this site which is for technical answerable questions. This question here is too broad and generally opinion-based. There are two many aspects to consider to give a useful answer here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I went by the suggestion on the right side which says: `We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.` and I am specifically asking if this is quantifiable so, i.e. no. of lines of code. Of course, I don't mind moving the question to another SE site if there is a more suitable one.

Comment: You would have to run a study, or otherwise collect data from both open source and closed source systems (perhaps by working in both environments and collecting stats), or maybe analyze the CVE database and classify those security flaws into open- vs. closed-source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about open source vs not open source, not about Unix vs non-Unix or about Unix variants. This question would be suitable with minor clarifications on [security.se], but the topic has already been covered at [Open Source vs Closed Source Systems](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4441/open-source-vs-closed-source-systems) and other questions tagged [opensource].